# .NET Remoting Server Only processes One request

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I am using .NET Remoting. My server/hoster is a Windows Service. It will sometimes work just fine and other times it will process one request and then it does not process any more (until I restart it). It is running as a Windows service  Here is the code from the Windows Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using Remoting;

namespace CreateReview
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        readonly TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(8180);

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            // Create an instance of a channel
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

            // Register as an available service with the name HelloWorld
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
                typeof(SampleObject),
                "SetupReview",
                WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help offered.

Vaccano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a SingleCall type, your SampleObject will be created for every call the client makes. This suggests to me that your object is at fault, and you don't show what it does. You need to look at any dependancies it has on shared resources orlocks. Try writing some debug out in the SampleObject's constructor to see how far the remoting call gets.